# Update python 2.7.6 to latest 2.7.x

Tags: python

My OS is Mint Linux and my python version is 2.7.6.

If there is no reason for NOT update, I would like to update it to the latest
2.7.x version.

I can't figure out a linux command which does this.
Is there a canonical way to update python?

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7
This ppa will help you.

And [this](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes) ppa contains different python versions from old ones to new.

Comment: Welcome! Please give a summary of what those web pages say. Links break all the time and, if those links break, there'll be nothing left in your answer. Also, the pages weren't loading for me when I tried just now.